# Why isn't quadratic variation of a brownian motion always t?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

If you look [here](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/mcudina/m339w_scaled_rnd_walks.pdf), on slide 24 the quadratic variation of a scaled random walk comes out to be t (the n doesn't matter as it cancels out).

A scaled random walk becomes a brownian motion as n approaches infinity.

So, why do we say that its t with probability 1 when we can make a stronger statement?

Alternatively, if that's not the case, how can we construct a path that can be a realisation of a brownian motion but where the quadratic variation isn't t?

Comment: The path given by $f(t)=0$ has, like every other completely defined path, zero probability of actually occurring. In a sense however it is is the single most likely realisation of Brownian Motion. And it is not a scaled random walk for any value of $n$.

Comment: Ah, so the set of paths we can generate from taking the limit of a scaled random walk doesn't contain all possible paths then. I wonder why do we use this procedure then. Is there a better random experiment that yields every possible path?